# I am using javascript api to display a map on my website and it works but when i change the values to database values it does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, maps

When I enter raw data for the longitude latitude, my code works fine.
Exemple here :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function my_map_add() {
        var myMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(28.5383866, 77.34916609);
        var myMapProp = {
            center: myMapCenter,
            zoom: 12,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_map_add"), myMapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myMapCenter
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    } 
</script>
```

But when i do this it does not work. ($id1 and $id2 are values from database)
Exemple :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function my_map_add() {
        var myMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng($id1, $id2);
        var myMapProp = {
            center: myMapCenter,
            zoom: 12,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_map_add"), myMapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myMapCenter
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: They seems to be php variables. What about using something like `var myMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $id1; ?>, <?php echo $id2; ?>);` ? You can't mix directly php and javascript.

Comment: What is your question tagged Java ?

Comment: where $id1 and $id2 declared ?

Comment: declared in a php file just above the script

Answer (score 0):

If `$id` is from PHP variable you must use echo like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_map_add() {
var myMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $id1.','.$id2; ?>); //here
var myMapProp = {center:myMapCenter, zoom:12, scrollwheel:false, draggable:false, 
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_map_add"),myMapProp);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myMapCenter});
marker.setMap(map);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure $id1 and $id2 exist? and have you tried to echo for see if value have correct format?